# Helm template not picking up override value

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I am trying to override default values from -f .YAML, and it seems that there are some logic error or it is unsupported.

values.yaml

```yaml
hive:
     siteXml:
         properties:
            - name: xyz.catalog.credentials.provider.factory.class
              # value: com.xyz.dataplatform.credentialproviders.xyz1CredentialsProvider
              value: com.xyz.auth.profile.ProfileCredentialsProvider
```

- overiding from .YAML values (failed to override).

```bash
helm template someinstall chartname -f myvalues.yaml
```

```yaml
hive:
  siteXml:
      properties:
         - name: xyz.catalog.credentials.provider.factory.class
           value: com.xyz.someplatform.credentialproviders.xyz1CredentialsProvider
```

Configmap.yaml logic

```yaml
{{- range $k, $v := .Values.hive.siteXml.properties }}
{{- if eq .name "xyz.catalog.credentials.provider.factory.class" }}
spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.xyz.credentials.provider={{ $v.value }}
{{- end }}
{{- end }}
```

Result:

```
spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.xyz.credentials.provider=com.xyz.auth.profile.ProfileCredentialsProvider
```

expected:

```
spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.xyz.credentials.provider=com.xyz.someplatform.credentialproviders.xyz1CredentialsProvider
```

Answer (score 0):

The above code is working fine if Dict values located on 1 single file, if values are concatenated then helm grab the values from value.yaml.

```
hive:
  siteXml:
      properties:
         - name: xyz.catalog.credentials.provider.factory.class
           value: com.xyz.someplatform.credentialproviders.xyz1CredentialsProvider
         - name: a
           value: b
         - name: c
           value: d
```